# Global existence for differential riccati equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations, control-theory

Consider an autonomous Riccati Differential Equation
$$
\dot{P} + A^\top P + P\,A − P\,B\,B^\top P + Q = 0,\quad P(0) = 0
$$

all matrices are real and continuous.
You can find in many textbooks existence and uniqueness on 
$(-\infty,0]$ under suitable conditions. 
Moreover $P(t)\rightarrow P_{\infty}$ for $t\rightarrow -\infty$ in a monotonic way, where $P_{\infty}$
is the unique symmetric positive semidefinite solution of 
$A^\top P + P\, A − P\, B\, B^\top P + Q = 0$.

What can be said about  existence on $(-\infty,\infty)$. 
Or has somebody an example for a finite-time blow up for $t\rightarrow +\infty$?

Comment: As a remark, while blow-up in finite time occur quite a lot for such systems, there are some interesting (non-generic) families for which the solution exists for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. For instance, for the vector-valued version, there is a famous 2-dimensional homogeneous example where you have a line through the origin, say y-axis, on which the homogeneous quadratic vector field vanishes, and the flows kind of spirals "from" the negative y-axis to the positive y-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\dot y = y^2$ is an instance of this problem class with blow-up in finite positive time for $y(0)>0$, as its well-known solution 
$$
y(t)=\frac{y(0)}{1-y(0)·t}
$$
has a pole at $t=\frac1{y(0)}$.

Answer (score 0):

One-dimensional counter-example: 
$$
A=0,\,B=1,\, Q=-1.
$$
Our initial value problem becomes
$$
p'-p^2-1=0,\quad p(0)=0,
$$
with UNIQUE solution
$$
p(t)=\tan t.
$$
Maximal domain of the solution $I=(\pi/2,\pi/2)$.